# Status Dashboard

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script

I know this question has probably been asked so many times before, but I can't find anything helpful out in the wide world.

I'm looking for a status dashboard for my company's websites, that I can host on a local server for our customers to view.

I came across: http://www.stashboard.org/. However, I'm really not interested in going down the Google app engine route. I'm looking for more of a local (perhaps PHP) route.

Any ideas?

Comment: Think I found an answer: https://github.com/bfirsh/whiskerboard

Comment: In that case, you should post that as an answer and mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I found an answer: [Whiskerboard](http://github.com/bfirsh/whiskerboard)